# Python- Trying to multiply items in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

So basically what I'm trying to do here is ask a user for a random string input, for example:

```
asdf34fh2
```

And I want to pull the numbers out of them into a list and get `[3,4,2]` but I keep getting `[34, 2]`.

```
import re 

def digit_product():        
    str1 = input("Enter a string with numbers: ")

    if str1.isalpha():
        print('Not a string with numbers')
        str1 = input("Enter a string with numbers: ")
    else:
        print(re.findall(r'\d+', str1))   

digit_product()
```

And then I want to take that list of numbers and multiply them, and ultimately get 24.

Comment: Don't use `str` as a variable name, it'll disable built-in function `str()` :)

Answer (score 7):

Your regular expression, `\d+`, is the culprit here. The `+` means it matches one or more consecutive digits (`\d`):

```
asdf34fh2
    ^-  ^
    \   \_ second match: one or more digits ("2")
     \____ first match: one or more digits ("34")
```

It looks like you only want to match one digit, so use `\d` without the `+`.

Comment: Thank you so much! crazy how one character throws the whole thing off

Answer (score 0):

Easiest to just use a comprehension, if you ask me.

```
>>> a = "asdf34fh2"
>>> [i for i in a if i in '0123456789']
['3', '4', '2']
```

or

```
>>> [i for i in a if i.isdigit()]
['3', '4', '2']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import functools

def digit_product():

    str=input("Enter a string with numbers: ")
    finded = re.findall(r'\d', str)
    if not finded:
        print('Not a string with numbers')
    else:
        return functools.reduce(lambda x, y: int(x) * int(y), finded)

def digit_product2():
    input_text = input("Enter a string with numbers: ")
    return functools.reduce(lambda x, y: int(x) * int(y), filter(str.isdigit, input_text))

>>> digit_product()
Enter a string with numbers: a2s2ddd44dd
64

>>> digit_product2()
Enter a string with numbers: a2s2ddd44dd
64
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a handy one-liner

```
print(reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, [int(n) for n in text_input if n.isdigit()]))
```

without the need to import `re`. You should avoid importing resources if you can do it with built-in functions.

Also avoid using `str` as a variable name. It's reserved for type string.

The `reduce(lambda …` part is hard to get at the beginning. But you can just use it to multiply all items in list.

**Algorithm Explanation**

First, all elements (characters) in the input string are checked. If a digit was detected it will be appended to a list as an integer. Then the list will be reduced to the factor of all elements inside.

You said nothing about a **zero value**. Take care of it, e.g.

```
print(reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, [int(n) for n in text_input if n.isdigit() and n is not '0']))
```

Answer (score -1):

Regular expressions are dead slow and often tricky to handle. For your purpose I would recommend built-in functional programming and list expressions:

```
In [115]: a = "asdf34fh2gh39qw3409sdgfklh"

In [116]: filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), a)
Out[116]: '342393409'

In [117]: [char for char in filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), a)]
Out[117]: ['3', '4', '2', '3', '9', '3', '4', '0', '9']
```